# Can I use Django's template to launch react JS?

Tags: django, reactjs

I found difficult to use Django Rest API with React JS as I am newbie (easy to make CRUD operation found difficult to handle user authentication ). 
Can I use regular Django (not Django Rest framework ) templates to render the react JS  ? I will user webpack to mount the Javascript file and hook it with Django templates

Comment: its not difficult to handle use auth in react api and django

Comment: if you want i show you a simple auth way

Comment: Seems odd to do so. Use django to handle api requests, create-react-app separate directory to serve to clients.

Comment: Yes you can use Django templates to render react.

Comment: @sina farhadi , Would you pls share Github repo of such project ?

Comment: hey if you want I have a blank base project using react webpack, django rest